# What is the efficient way to extract and rename all variable names to another human language. Is there a good script or extension?

Tags: datatable, extract, rename

How can I easily extract and rename all variables / functions ?

I need a VS-Code Extension or a Javascript or even a Batch script that takes the code as INPUT and tables out all the Language specific parameters (function, variable, class names etc) Then I myself will translate to another language all words in the table. Finally the script/extension would rename all the corresponding words with their translated camelCase versions.

Any ideas ?